# PHP5 - variable generate foreach issue on output

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays, "$numbers" and "$letters" :

```
$numbers = array(0 => "0", 1 => "1", 2 => "2", 3 => "3");
$letters = array(0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3 => "d");
```

I'm using foreach loop related to my arrays:

```
foreach(array_combine($numbers, $letters) as $n => $l){
    echo ${$l.'[0]'.}.' = array_keys('.'$car_images'.'['.$n.'])'.'<br>';
}
```

to get this following output:

```
/* Expected Output:
    $a[0] = array_keys($car_images[0]);
    $b[0] = array_keys($car_images[1]);
    $c[0] = array_keys($car_images[2]);
    */
```

Which i'm failing to get related to parenthesis error, thanks for helping me.

Comment: You know you can drop the array_combine line, and the $numbers array.  And achieve the same by iterating on the $letters array?  Or rather `array_combine($numbers, $letters)` is the equivalent of `$letters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly plan to do with that string, but it is dangerous. Anyway, here is how it can be achieved:

```
$numbers = array(0 => "0", 1 => "1", 2 => "2", 3 => "3");
$letters = array(0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3 => "d");

foreach(array_combine($numbers, $letters) as $n => $l){
    echo "\${$l}[0] = array_keys(\$car_images[{$n}])<br>";
}
```

Your code has a lot of syntax errors and this resolves that.

Comment: Is there any security issue related to that ?

Comment: I'm sending those variable to a caroussel, every variable has a url image

Comment: @aliouawalid I can't say exactly, because I don't know how you plan to use this, but you'll probably have to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute this, and even on the php.net page for eval it mentions how dangerous this is.